# Uniform convergence for infinity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I just read in the Sotomayor Differential Equations book (in case reference is needed it is page 257, although my question is somewhat general) that a function converges uniformly for infinity. What is the meaning of that term? Since the notion of convergence that I have is that it must be finite. Any clear and concise idea?

**For example in Sotomayor take the following:**

> Let $G(u)$ is bounded and $v'(t)<0$ with $v_0\geq v(t)\geq v_0-2t$. Also $u'(t)>0$ then
> $$\int\frac{1}{v(u)-G(u)}du$$
> the integral approaches zero monotonically, since the denominator uniformly converge to $\infty$ as $v_0\to\infty$.

[image]

Comment: It would help to have more context, rather than a mere paraphrase.

Comment: As stated, it would appear to be false. The integral is indefinite, and therefore cannot be defined except up to an arbitrary additive constant. Quite obviously, it can only approach $0$ for at most one value of that constant. But perhaps there was something in the greater context of this snippet that would change the interpretation of the expression? Your pictured text that follows is to us just a car-wreck of undefined symbolry.

Comment: You are very right, what I have written would be quasi-false (the integral must be defined), what happens is that I do not know how to write it since the text has many accounts behind that integral, that is why I mentioned the page and put only one fraction of the text.

Comment: You have $G_+\ge G(u)\ge G_-$, thus $v_0-G_-\ge v(u)-G(u)\ge v_0-G_+-2t$. If $t$ is inside some fixed interval, this gives uniform divergence to infinity for $v_0\to\infty$. Here "uniform" means that there are no points with faster or slower divergence.